# Make ZipFile write a backslash to a filename

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I want my zipped filenames to contain a backlash, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. Currently I use:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipObj = ZipFile('sample.zip', 'w')
zipObj.write("sampleFile.png", "\sampleName.png")
zipObj.close()
```

It simply omits the backlash in the filename.

Comment: You could try to prefix the string with the backslash with `r`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that didn't work either